# How do I correctly remove a JavaScript file in php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with removing JavaScript file in functions.php in WordPress.

This is the file I want to remove:

```
../js/scripts/wc/productFilters.min.js?ver=6.1.4' id='wd-product-filters-js'></script>
```

And this is my code. I put it on functions.php but it didn't work:

```
function dequeue_filter_js() {
   wp_dequeue_script( 'wd-product-filters' );
   wp_deregister_script( 'wd-product-filters' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dequeue_filter_js', 1000 );
```

Thank You in Advance

Comment: Use an absolute path